# Additivization of functors in an abelian monoidal category (crosspost from MSE)

Tags: ct.category-theory

I posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697326/additivization-of-functors-in-an-abelian-monoidal-category) a week ago on math.stackexchange. As is sometimes the case, I got no answers. Considering that the question is about a research article, I hope that it might be relevant for MathOverflow.

Here is the original question:

---

I'm having trouble with the proof of Lemma 2.9 in "[Cohomology of Monoids in Monoidal Categories](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.25.3891&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" by Baues, Jibladze, and Tonks, and I was wondering if someone could clarify a detail. I'll try to summarize the context of the lemma.

### Context

Let $(\Bbb A,\circ,I)$ be an monoidal category where $\Bbb A$ is abelian: in particular, $\circ$ is not necessarily additive in both arguments. Suppose that $\circ$ is left distributive, i.e. the natural transformation
$$(X_1\circ Y)\oplus(X_2\circ Y)\rightarrow (X_1\oplus X_2)\circ Y$$
is an isomorphism. For example, $\Bbb A$ could be the category of linear operads (this is a motivating example of the article). Given an endofunctor $F$ of $\Bbb A$, we define its *cross-effect*
$$F(A|B):=\ker(F(A\oplus B)\rightarrow F(A)\oplus F(B)).$$
The *additivization* of $F$ is then the functor $F^\text{add}$ defined by
$$F^\text{add}(A):=\text{coker}\left(F(A|A)\rightarrow F(A\oplus A)\xrightarrow{F(+)}F(A)\right).$$
The idea is that $F^\text{add}$ is the additive part of $F$.

Let $(M,\mu,\eta)$ be an internal monoid in $\Bbb A$, and let $L_0$ be the endofunctor of $\Bbb A$ defined by $L_0(A)=M\circ(M\oplus A)$. Let $L:=L_0^\text{add}$ be the additivization of $L_0$. (In the case of operads, represented as planar trees, I see $L(A)$ as the space of trees whose nodes are all labeled by elements of $M$ except for one leaf, which is labeled by an element of $A$.)

Suppose now that $\Bbb A$ is *right compatible with cokernels*, i.e. that

> for each $A\in\Bbb A$, the additive functor $A\circ-:\Bbb A\rightarrow\Bbb A$ given by $B\mapsto A\circ B$ preserves cokernels.

Then, in the proof of Lemma 2.9, the authors claim the following:

> By the assumption that $\Bbb A$ is right compatible with cokernels it follows that $L(L(X))$ is the additivisation of $L_0(L_0(X))$ in $X$ [...].

### Remarks

If anyone could **provide an explanation of the last claim**, I would be very grateful. However, my inability to understand how to show this might be related to two other issues I have:

1) Elsewhere in the literature, cross-effects are only defined when $F$ is *reduced*, i.e. $F(0)=0$ (e.g. [here](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~vespa/Cours-Tokyo-2019.pdf), section 2). But we can always reduce a functor by taking the cokernel of $F(0)\rightarrow F(X)$, so I don't think it's much of a problem.

2) In the first quote, the authors state that $A\circ -$ is additive, which is quite the opposite of the initial hypothesis that $\circ$ be *left* distributive, and not necessarily *right* distributive. How to resolve this apparent conflict?